# Trouble understanding type indexing

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I'm having trouble understanding the following type definition:

```
type MergeHandlersReturnType<H extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof H]: ReturnType<H[K]>
}[keyof H]
```

Decomposing the above definition using similar types I'm not getting why the following is giving me compiler errors

```
interface R1 extends Record<string, any> {
  "key1": () => 0|1
}

const v1: R1 = {
  "key1": () => 1,
  "key2": () => 2,
  "key3": () => 3
}

type Merged<R1> = {
  [K in keyof R1]: ReturnType<R1[K]>
                              ^^^^^
    }[keyof R1]


Type 'R1[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'R1[keyof R1]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type 'R1[string] | R1[number] | R1[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
      Type 'R1[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.ts(2344)
```

I was expecting the `Merged` type to be the unions of the return types of the keys of `R1` but the indexing is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why you are seeing a compiler error:

1. `Merged<R1>` is stating that `R1` is a name of a generic type variable, not the `R1` interface, hence `R1` in `Merged` is pretty much like generic `T` which has no type definition and hypothetically has no properties that can be accessed via `T[K]`.
2. After changing `Merged<R1>` to `Merged`, because `Record` has a type of `any` in `interface R1 extends Record<string, any> {`, the resulting `Merged` union type will always be `any`... `ReturnType` in `[K in keyof R1]: ReturnType<R1[K]>` looks at what the second parameter of `Record` is as it is the broader one and does not analyze the properties inside the `R1` interface. To fix this, I would advise you to add a specific type instead of the `any` like so: `interface R1 extends Record<string,() => 0|1|2|3> {`. Ofcourse another way would be to get rid of the extends and define your keys with your types so you wouldn't have to define the union type manually and use `Merged` like you want to:

```
interface R1 {
  "key1": () => 0|1
  "key2": () => 2,
  "key3": () => 3
}
```

It really depends on your use case and hopefully above explains why you are seeing the error in your question.

Here is a link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoEZkQB6RAEwGc0IEB7KfAHkLClAHMAaZACgEpkBeAPmQAYAPukEAmQQGY%20AbwCwAKGTIARAGsIAT3TKAXG068BwhQF8FCgPQXkAQQA2kKCDhhgANxQZL10I-hI0TDl5KyUVdS1dfW4%20IXRvMLVNUSiOGORRJgSlJI0JVIM%20CQSzeXN5chBaZDd0PQxuZGCciO09NMN0LMVw5IL0zIUWzXz2wuRi%20VKFMA0ABxQAWWgGCHxG5uQAbQBpZFBkCLIYQIBdeogwAFcnABV5iCoMXdOeUy2jk4xT8qA).

Answer (score 0):

The generic parameter `R1` must extend `Record<string, any>` for this to work, or its assumed to be any.

Or more precisely, it needs to extend a type that supports [indexed signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

If you compare your definition of `Merged<>` to the original you should be able to see that you are missing the constraint.

```
interface R1 extends Record<string, any> {
  "key1": () => 0|1
}

const v1: R1 = {
  "key1": () => 1,
  "key2": () => 2,
  "key3": () => 3
}

interface MyType {
  [k: string]: any
}

type MergedForMyType<R1 extends MyType> = {
  [K in keyof R1]: ReturnType<R1[K]>
} [keyof R1]

type MergedForRecordGeneric<R1 extends MyType | Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof R1]: ReturnType<R1[K]>
} [keyof R1]
```